# How to get the current mouse pointer shape?

Tags: mouse, cursor

I know that you can use xinput to track the mouse position and click events, but I was looking for the ability to know what is the current mouse pointer/cursor shape.

For example, is it the normal arrow select shape, the hand, text select pointer, etc.

Is there command that would show the current mouse pointer state or maybe a log that keeps track of that information?